# How to specify the superuser of a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create a PostgreSQL database and be able to connect as a user which is specified at creation. Therefore I'm using `initdb` and `createdb`. However the `initdb --user`/`-U` option seems to be ignored:

```
> cd `mktemp -d`
> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/initdb --user=user1 test1
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "richter".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "de_DE.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "german".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory test1 ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D test1 -l logfile start
```

The connection with `createdb` after starting the server with the `postgres` command fails because `user1` isn't available. `richter` is the user executing the command.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are mixing up database users and operating system users.

   Since you run `initdb` as OS user `richter`, that user will own the database files and the database server process.

   The user `user1` is a database superuser.
2. You have to specify the database user with the `--username` or `-U` option with `psql`, `createdb` and other PostgreSQL client applications.

You should show commands and error messages rather than saying “the connection fails”.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that escaping usernames in the long options is difficult - I didn't systemtically investigate all combinations of no, single and double quotes, but using `-U` without quotes worked fine for me.

Comment: One word of advice here: always use only lowercase ASCII characters, numbers and the underscore for database object names (including users). You'll save yourself a lot of trouble, and you never need to quote or escape anything.